# How to package Angular (front-end) and Node.js (server) applications together

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am building an Angular 8 front-end application, and a Node.js web application using Express framework to serve as the backend of the application. The Express-based server-side web application will expose a REST API, that will be consumed by the Angular application, which in turn may make HTTP calls to external services.

For specific reasons, I need to distribute the two applications together. I also want to manage development of both applications as a single project. I have searched for good practices online, and I have seen several approaches, such as:

- Serve the Angular application almost like a static set of files in a directory within the Node.js web application
- Use a package like `concurrently` to run the Angular and Node.js applications simultaneously, by defining a script in the top-level folder's `package.json` file.

I imagine there are multiple ways of achieving this, and I hope someone can share an approach on a well trodden path, using the same or similar stack.

**Update Oct 21 2019** I want to provide some context on my specific requirement. I don't plan to host this on an external server. Ultimately, my goal is to create an Electron app that will encapsulate the front-end and the web application. I am currently prototyping this for local development and execution, and distributing to a few users for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying an Angular application it should be delivered as static asset files (html, js, css - or bundles) and then served by a regular web server. So your first approach looks about right. When accessing your own backend you don‘t have to care about CORS issues since the requests will be same origin.

The second idea looks like you want to use the Angular CLI development server, which is not a good idea for production. So I would not go that way.

As an alternative you could make use of containers and provide an Angular container for the frontend (f.e. using nginx to serve the assets) and a second container for the node application. These could be integrated using a properly configured reverse proxy or deployed to kubernetes as a pod with an Ingress in front (which is a reverse proxy after all).

Comment: What is the best way to proceed with the first approach? I have seen several forms and I hope to be pointed to the _best practices_ way of implementing this. This entails serving static/asset files (such as images, CSS, JS. etc.) and then application files. Also need to setup a proxy configuration presumably to work around CORS

Comment: That really depends on your environment and (build) infrastructure. The simplest approach is to use the angular cli, create a production build and serve the result as static assets from your node/express backend

Comment: How do I implement the first approach? Searching yields some complicated examples, so I am looking to see if there is a specific way to serve an Angular app within an Express app project.

Answer (score 1):

The Nrwl Nx set of tools would be perfect for this. It's used in enterprises for mono-repo setups - especially Angular and Express/NestJs. Here's an article that acts as a guide to getting up and running with it

https://blog.nrwl.io/building-full-stack-applications-using-angular-cli-and-nx-5eff205248f1

Comment: This is very useful to know, for more complex projects. Thanks! At this point, I want to keep things as simple as possible, given that I know that it will be a single Angular project backed by a single Express web application.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Cloud Platform is an option, create a project and host frontend and backend applications.

1. **Firebase Hosting**

   - use Firebase Hosting for Angular App
   - Setup a hosting rewrite to redirect "API" routes to Cloud Run
2. **Google Cloud Run**

   - Use Cloud Run to serve NodeJs app

Comment: Is Firebase hosting of the Angular app similar to hosting a static website on S3 (AWS)? I don't plan to host this on an external server. Ultimately, the plan is to create an Electron app that will encapsulate the front end and the web application. I am currently prototyping this for local development and execution, and distributing to a few users for review.

Comment: Yes, it´s a static hosting fo web apps. Ok I get it, if it´s an electron app then this option is not valid.